# Modal sheet not working in applicationdidfinishlaunching?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, modal-dialog, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to get a sheet to display modally when the app finishes launching.  If I place the code in a generic action and execute it somewhere after app launch, it works as desired and the sheet drops down nicely. If I take the same code and place it in applicationdidfinishlaunching, the sheet displays as a separate window (which is not what I need).

```
 [NSApp beginSheet:settingsWindow
   modalForWindow:[NSApp keyWindow]
    modalDelegate:nil
   didEndSelector:nil
      contextInfo:nil];
[NSApp runModalForWindow:settingsWindow];

[NSApp endSheet:settingsWindow];
[settingsWindow orderOut:self];
```

The visible at launch option is disabled.  Grateful for any suggestions.  I also tried it in awakefromnib with the same incorrect result.

Edit: Using [self performSelector:@selector(someAction:) withObject:self afterDelay:0.5]; where the contents of someAction are as above, yields the correct result. Why is this?

Comment: keyWindow method might return nil if the application’s nib file hasn’t finished loading yet or if the receiver is not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSApp`'s `beginSheet: modalForWindow: modalDelegate: didEndSelector: contextInfo:` and `endSheet:` are [deprecated in OS X 10.10](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:). You should instead use [beginSheet: completionHandler: on NSWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/beginSheet:completionHandler:) instance to show the sheet window modally.

```
NSWindow *mainWindow = [NSApp windows][0]; 
[mainWindow beginSheet:settingsWindow completionHandler: nil];
```

By the way, does the `[NSApp keyWindow]` return an instance in `didFinishLaunching`?

Comment: thanks for the deprecation tip - I hadn't spotted that.